# Identifying which close-by number corresponds to which input

Tags: python, list, identification

**Context:** I have a bit of an odd problem: let's consider 2 tuples, one of which is a subset from the other of size N-1.

```
node = (40, 50, 60, 80)
adj_node = (40, 50, 60)
```

As you can see, I refer to those combinations as nodes from a network graph. The prefix `adj_` stands for `adjacent`. The algorithm is coloring the graph, i.e. it finds an alternative value for each node. The suffix`alt_` will stand for `alternative`.

Both the `node` and the `adj_node` are provided with 1 alternative within a tolerance range. The goal of this function is to compute the deviation between both alternatives.

```
def compute_deviation_between_node_alternative_and_adj_node_alternative(node,
                                            node_alt, adj_node, adj_node_alt):
"""
4 tuples in input, the node, the node alternative, the adjacent node, and 
the adjacent node alternatives.
"""
# Compute
return deviation
```

Let's consider the following input:

```
node = (40, 50, 60, 80)
node_alt = (39, 48, 59, 87)
adj_node = (40, 50, 60)
adj_node_alt = (42, 55, 59)
```

Each value from the node or from adj_node is replaced by an alternative value within a +/- 10% tolerance band. Thus, `40` becames `39` in the  node alternative and `42` in the adjacent node_alternative.
The alternatives may not be ordered. i.e. `node_alt` could have been `(48, 39, 87, 59)`.
The tolerance band may overlap, e.g. for `60`, both `55` and `59` are within the tolerance band.

**Problematic part of the code:** The step I am trying to implement is what I called an identification step: figure out which alternative value corresponds to which input value. To do so, I compute the distance between the values and return the id (or idx) at which the alternative value is located.

```
tolerances = [0.1 if x <= 100 else 0.2 for x in node]
distance = dict()
alt_identification = dict()
for k, x in enumerate(node):
    distance[k] = [abs(elt-1) for elt in [alt_x/x for alt_x in node_alt]]
    alt_identification[x] = list(np.where([elt <= tolerances[k]+0.00001 for elt in distance[k]])[0])
```

With the example above, the output is:

```
alt_identification
Out[67]: {40: [0], 50: [1], 60: [2], 80: [3]}
```

The same is done for the adjacent node alternative.

```
distance = dict()
adj_alt_identification = dict()
for k, x in enumerate(node):
    distance[k] = [abs(elt-1) for elt in [alt_x/x for alt_x in adj_node_alt]]
    adj_alt_identification[x] = list(np.where([elt <= tolerances[k]+0.00001 for elt in distance[k]])[0])
```

Output:

```
adj_alt_identification
Out[66]: {40: [0], 50: [1], 60: [1, 2], 80: []}
```

**Problem:** I have different scenarios which could occur.

Scenario 1: each value has been identified to one alternative value. For instance, that's the case for `node` where the output is `{40: [0], 50: [1], 60: [2], 80: [3]}`.

Scenario 2: Some of the input values are identified to 2 or more different possible alternative values. This can happen because of the tolerance band overlapping. e.g.

```
adj_node = (40, 50, 60)
adj_node_alt = (42, 55, 54)
```

Both `55` and `54` are included in the tolerance band from `50` and `60`.
The output would be (if the node is `(40, 50, 60, 80)`):

adj_alt_identification
   Out[66]: {40: [0], 50: [1, 2], 60: [1, 2], 80: []}

Scenario 3: This is the case in the previous example for `adj_alt`:

```
adj_node = (40, 50, 60)
adj_node_alt = (42, 55, 59)
```

`55` and `59` are included in the tolerance band of `60`.
Only `55` is included in the tolerance band of `50`.

The current output is:

```
adj_alt_identification
Out[66]: {40: [0], 50: [1], 60: [1, 2], 80: []}
```

A corret output would figure out that `60` can not take the value `55` since it is already taken by `50`. Thus, the output should be:

```
adj_alt_identification
Out[66]: {40: [0], 50: [1], 60: [2], 80: []}
```

If anyone has any idea on how to improve this code, and on how to get the correct output in every scenario, I would gladly hear about it :) I feel like my identification process is clumsy and inefficient...

Answer (score 0):

Current code resulting in the correct output: It's a mess and clearly inefficient...

```
def traceback(tuple_node, tuple_node_alt):
    """
    Compute which value from tuple_node_alt comes from which value from tuple_node.
    tuple_node is the input
    tuple_node_alt is the "output"
    """
    # Compute the tolerances based on the node
    tolerances = [0.1 if f <= 100 else 0.2 for f in tuple_node]

    # Traceback
    distance = dict()
    alt_identification = dict()
    for k, x in enumerate(tuple_node):
        distance[k] = [abs(elt-1) for elt in [alt_x/x for alt_x in tuple_node_alt]]
        alt_identification[x] = list(np.where([elt <= tolerances[k]+0.00001 for elt in distance[k]])[0])

    len_values = {key: len(val) for key, val in alt_identification.items()}

    if all([x <= 1 for x in len_values.values()]):
        return alt_identification
    else:
        for key, value in alt_identification.items():
            if len(value) <= 1:
                continue
            else:
                other_values = [val for k, val in alt_identification.items() if k != key]
                if value in other_values:
                   continue
                else:
                    for val in other_values:
                        set1 = set(value)
                        intersec = set1.intersection(set(val))
                        if len(intersec) == 0:
                            continue
                        else:
                            alt_identification[key] = [v for v in value if v not in intersec]

    return alt_identification
```